# Radio button not recognized in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9

I have updated Angular from version 8 to 9. I have observed that in app.module.ts, the following has changed from

```
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material';
```

To

```
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
```

Now, I am getting the following error on ng build.

> 1. If 'mat-radio-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-radio-button' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message.

I have tried adding CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA or NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA to app module with no luck.

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
```

What will be the issue? Thanks!!

**Update:**

I have found similar issue here:
[Angular compilation fails after upgrade to Angular v9 and enabling Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931739/angular-compilation-fails-after-upgrade-to-angular-v9-and-enabling-ivy)

Comment: Did you  included ```MatRadioModule``` inside ```imports``` array in ```app.module.ts``` file??

Comment: In which module your component is registered/declared? If it is app.module.ts then check imports: [MatRadioModule]

Comment: @ManiRaj Yes, I have included MatRadioModule inside imports array in app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're using `<mat-radio-button></mat-radio-button>` within a module where `MatRadioModule` is not imported.

Firstly, you'll need to add `angular/material` and `angular/cdk` as dependencies to your project.

To correctly import `MatRadioModule`, make sure it is imported in the module, where you are using `<mat-radio-button></mat-radio-button>`

Like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatRadioModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now I can use it in my template like this: (within `AppModule`)

```
<mat-radio-button></mat-radio-button>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c8kmds

Make sure you followed all those steps and make sure that `MatRadioModule` is imported in the right `Module`

Comment: still facing the same issue.

Comment: @Pearl If you can, try to create a reproducer of the issue on stackblitz. Iam suspecting the Upgrade to V9 hasn't changed all the imports and messed something up. The error message should give you a hint as to where the error occured.

Comment: In the url: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/18489, he uses ([ngModel]) instead of [(ngModel])? Will it resolve the issue?

Comment: `[(ngModel)]` is the correct way to two-way bind a property, there's no telling what's wrong in your application without a reproducible example.

Comment: Mike, I came across similar issue, hope it will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931739/angular-compilation-fails-after-upgrade-to-angular-v9-and-enabling-ivy